# CRC computation OK for small payloads but not for large ones

Tags: crc, crc16

I am trying to validate the CRC associated with the messages from my heater and received through an RTL-SDR dongle. The messages are issued by a Semtech SX1211 transmitter in the Variable Length Packet Format mode. The datasheet says that CRC encoding is performed using a CRC16 algo and a 0x1021 polynom.
The payload on which the CRC computation is done is: size of payload on 1 byte followed by the payload.
The payloads issued by my heater can be 10, 15, 17, 23, 49 or 63 bytes long.

For size of payload equals to 10, 15 and 17 I was able to find an initial CRC value - thanks to [CRC reveng](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/) - which is returning the appropriate CRC value for each received payload of a given size. e.g. for "0f2080835c8117082303291809492003" I get an initial value of 0xb71e which can be successfully applied to all the 15 bytes long messages. I have got 3 initial CRC values which are different for each size.

```
./reveng -w16 -p 0x1021 -i 0xb71e -c 0f2080835c8117082303291809492003
29f1
```

But I am not able to find a solution for 23, 49 and 63 bytes long records. The brute force program I wrote to find the initial value for 10, 15 & 17 long records give different values for longer records of a given size.
Any ideas too solve this problem would be appreciated.
Follows a sample of 23 bytes long records with the CRC I am supposed to obtain given at the end of each records (after the space):

```
178008be0c0117a0290015a02f00040800c300c300250000 da05
178008be140017a0290005a02f00000800c4004100010000 136d
178008be1800074052002b405e00081000860186000a0000 c2b8
178008be1c0117a0290015a02f000408004300c300010000 3790
178008be200117a0290015a02f00040800c300c300050000 e110
178008be240117a0290015a02f00040800c300c300050000 37dc
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It seems unlikely that anybody would have used a CRC initial value that is different for different lengths.  Far more likely that you're computing the CRC over the wrong portion of the payload - if you do/don't include the length byte when you shouldn't/should, you'd get exactly this behavior (an error in the result that is constant for any given message length, and therefore could be calibrated out via the initial value, but only for messages of the same length).

Comment: I agree with what you say. But I am stuck at this stage. reveng with the -s param does not find any result for 23 bytes records. Any suggestion on how I should proceed ?

Comment: You are not correctly identifying the bytes on which to calculate the CRC. I can't even make any sense of "size of payload on 1 byte followed by the payload". Can you provide a link to the documentation?

Comment: I am pretty sure I am identifying correctly the bytes on which to calculate the CRC and I do not see the issue of having a 1 byte lenght with a payload with a max size of 64 bytes. The documentation of the SX1211 [is available here](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#E0000000JelG/a/44000000MDkD/qpueUKOM5fKdLmudwX7QsIsmQt5ZpJDyvc8Mxdj_wJc). See page 51 for the structure of the variable lenght packets format.

Comment: I could not understand your English. Now that I see the data sheet, I can see what you were trying to say about the span of the calculation.

Comment: There is something wrong with the data you provided (six examples of 24-byte payloads). There does not exist _any_ 16-bit CRC, with any polynomial, any bit ordering, any initial value, any final exclusive-or, or any ordering of the two CRC bytes that can generate the provided CRCs.

Comment: @Mark Adler: I agree. I'll play around with the parameters of the rtl_433 program I am using to decode my messages. Since the problems occur with the longer messages I am starting to think about reducing a bit the size of the pulse (40us) to see if it helps. But I am totally open to any other idea